# Leopard Macbook very slow after waking up from sleep / cron?

Tags: macos, cron

Problem:

- Occasionally, my Macbook becomes very slow after waking up from sleep
- I open Activity Monitor and notice some processes like `makewhatis` are taking 100% CPU
- I kill the process[es] and then everything works fine again

Questions:

- My guess is that these processes are cron jobs. Is that correct?
- Is it ok to kill them?
- Is there a way to make this problem not happen?
- Is this fixed on Snow Leopard?

I'm using Leopard (10.5.8) on a MacBook5,1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost certainly seeing the effects of `launchd` starting the `periodic daily`, `periodic weekly`, and `periodic monthly` routine system maintenance jobs, which do things like roll the logs and delete unused temporary files. Those jobs usually run at 3 in the morning, but if your machine was asleep at that time, `launchd` starts them the next time your machine wakes up.

The job that probably runs the longest and slows the system the most with a lot of disk I/O is the weekly (3AM Saturday morning) `makewhatis` job, which updates the filename database used by the traditional Unix `locate` command (sorta like an old-school mds/Spotlight). You can disable this in `/etc/defaults/periodic.conf` by changing the line

```
weekly_whatis_enable="YES"
```

to

```
weekly_whatis_enable="NO"
```

If you've added or modified a large number of files on your system, the next time `makewhatis` runs, it may take a long time.  If you kill it every time and it never completes, then the next week it'll have to start over again.  I'm not usually bothered by `makewhatis`, even though my system is not fast, especially my disk.  The only time I really notice it is when I've added a huge number of files to my system, like after checking out the entire source tree of the NetBSD operating system.

If `makewhatis` and the other `periodic` jobs don't turn out to be your whole problem, be aware that `launchd` provides the defer-to-the-next-wake service to any `launchd` job that uses the `StartCalendarInterval` key. Here's a way to quickly see which launchd jobs on your system use that key:

```
grep -r StartCalendarInterval {/System,,~}/Library/Launch{Daemons,Agents}/
```

(NB: I think the curly braces in that statement may be a `bash`-ism)

Answer (score 1):

To see if they are  cron jobs .... do a

```
crontab -l
```

in Terminal

You'll most likely get

```
crontab: no crontab for (user)
```

most scheduled jobs are handled by launchd in 10.5 and up.

To check for scheduled jobs that are controlled by launchd, do a

```
sudo launchctl list
```

If you see any of the jobs returning a `1` That is an indication it is having an issue.

Comment: Of interest might be if these are enabled in /System/Library/LaunchDaemons: com.apple.locate.plist and com.vix.cron.plist